# Looking for scriptural reference of Shanta Durga

Tags: scripture, identification-request, devi, durga

There is a form of mother Durga by name Shanta Durga which is worshiped almost everywhere in Goa. In fact, many houses names are after mother's name. When we enquire there about it from local people, they said She is devi of this whole area. This sounds fascinating as Goa is full of churches and less temples.
So my question is, is this form of mother mentioned in any scripture? If yes what is her origin and other details?

There is a famous temple in middle of the market of Calangute, Goa. Here is Google link to that temple: [Shree Shantha Durga temple](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&client=ms-android-samsung-ga-rev1&sxsrf=AOaemvLqPFNNpmW0ui996TRwQT1Qjp1evQ:1640021256948&q=Shree+Shantadurga+Samsthaana&ludocid=965834391882156774&gsas=1&client=ms-android-samsung-ga-rev1&ibp=gwp;0,7&lsig=AB86z5W8eAwAeAGkjiiS2bJB4k0M&kgs=4dbfb0d5be7b9e53&shndl=-1&source=sh/x/kp/local/2&entrypoint=sh/x/kp/local)

Comment: It would be useful if you can add any picture or temple about Shanta Durga for identification

Comment: @Pandya added temple reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Is this form of mother mentioned in any scripture?
```

**Yes**

Shanta Durga form of the mother is mentioned in [Sahyadri Khanda of the Skanda Purana](https://archive.org/details/Sahyadri-Khanda). Its English translation is unavailable.

[image]

> इति श्रीस्कादे उत्तररहस्ये सल्यादिखण्डे नागाव्दयमाहाःम्ये
> सूतशौनकसंवादे **शान्तादुर्गा**प्रादुभौवो नाम दहिनीयोऽ ध्यायः
>
> [page](https://ia802206.us.archive.org/21/items/Sahyadri-Khanda/Da-Cunha_Sahyadrikhanda_1877.pdf#page=522)

So, the above title contains the name Shanta Durga. And the chapters contain the total story in which Durga manifested as Shanta Durga.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shantadurga#Origins) mentions it with a citation (As the scripture is completely in Sanskrit, I am quoting the gist from Wikipedia)

> The second chapter of the Sanskrit Nāgavya Mahātmya, Śāntādurgā
> prādurbhāvaḥ, is a part of Sahyādrikhaṇḍa which is the chapter of
> Skanda Purana gives detail about this. Only the title of the
> chapter mentions the goddess Shantadurga and no where else is this
> epithet of the goddess mentioned. This section refers to a certain
> sage Śāntāmuni, a resident of Nagavya (modern Nagoa). The goddess
> appeared before Shantamuni and hence she's known as Shantadurga.

```
If yes what is her origin and other details.
```

Shanta Durga is also called Santeri. As we have already seen one of her manifestations in Skanda Purana. The following is mentioned by the temple website about another manifestation of Durga in the form of Shantadurga

> Shree Shantadurga is one of the forms of Goddess Adimaya Durga. It is
> believed that once there was a fierce war between Lord Shiva and Lord
> Vishnu due to which the entire world was distressed. Hence Lord
> Bramhadeva prayed and beseeched Goddess Adimaya Durga to intervene and
> stop the war. The Goddess held Lord Shiva by one hand and Lord Vishnu
> by the other hand and brought about reconciliation among them. This
> stopped the war and brought peace to the world. This form of the
> Goddess Adimaya Durga, is known as Shree Shantadurga.

This story seems to be present in the Marathi book named **Koṅkaṇa Mahātmya** as per some sources [1](https://youtu.be/nOR-FH79R7A?t=163) including Wikipedia and the book is unavailable online.

(The video source explicitly says that Koṅkaṇa Mahātmya contains the whole episode of the manifestation of Shantadurga mentioned by the temple website.)

Comment: You can use google translate for reference which is good enough and translate later sentence on your own.

Comment: Thanks, @TheDestroyer. I will try to do it accordingly.

Comment: Yes..This is correct answer. Upvoted :)

Comment: Do not use Wikipedia as a source.

Comment: Ha, @TheLittleNaruto I didn't use it as a source actually. But, I need to read two chapters of the scripture, which is in Sanskrit and then need to give a gist. Instead of that I just used it, but not as a source. You can check the scripture and chapters also in the 'page' link. And the video is in Telugu, so I told 'Wikipedia also mentions it'.

Comment: And, wiki contains a citation of a history book, which is also unavailable online.

Comment: This answer directly explains shanta durga. Good answer.

Comment: @hanugm ji, if you allow can I add some more info to your answer? Because I found a new reference in a tantra too. But its just of 2 to 3 lines so I thought of not making a new answer and rather add it to the existing one here.

Comment: @Chamundadas Don't worry add a new answer of your own. Because it deserves a new answer.

Comment: @hanugm sure, thanks alot.

Answer (score -1):

There's mention of a deity, (Yoginī to be precise) named Śāntā in the Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa.

In any case, here goes -

> #### [Verse 3.2.22.11b,12a](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423643.html), Skanda-purāṇa
>
> स्थाने नैर्ऋतिदिग्भागे **शांता शांतिप्रदायिनी** ॥ ११.ख ॥
>  सिंहोपरि
> समासीना चतुर्हस्ता वरप्रदा ॥ १२.क ॥
>
> > - In the spot, in the South-West, **Śāntā, the bestower of peace,** is
> >   seated on a lion. She has four hands and she grants boons.

There are many other references to goddess Śāntā in the Skanda Purāṇa. However, she's mentioned in connection to the Dharmāraṇya tirtha region, not sure if she is the same presiding deity of the temple in Goa. And also, the story mentioned in the temples website of her stopping a war between Shiva & Vishnu isn't mentioned in the Skanda Purāṇa.

But, since all forms are of the one Supreme Goddess, so perhaps there exists a similar connection here too.